# Why won’t this script work in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

gs:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range; 
  if (range.getA1Notation() === "B4") {
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange("C5:OG22").getValues();
    sheet.getRange("B5:OF22").setValues(values);
  }
}
```

I was expecting this to work and move dated specified cells over one column.

Comment: What was the error?  Check your execution log.  Are you sure you have 395 columns?

Comment: Did you save the script?

Comment: Yes I do have 395 columns I’m trying to do a moving calendar with peoples schedules and a drop down for each day to go available for shifts. I did save it as well.

Comment: Did you check your execution logs to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Yes I did and there were I think it was from running it in the editor where it cant get the change from the sheet?

Comment: You can't run it without supplying the event object that the trigger provides.  Is that the answer you seek  or something else.

Comment: How do I run it then cause I can change the date in B4 but it doesn’t do anything?

Comment: Check your executions log to find out why? Learn how to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Sheet0" || e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart != 4) return;
  //e.source.toast("Gate")
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var vs = sh.getRange("A5:J5").getValues();
  sh.getRange("B6:K6").setValues(vs);
}
```

I think it might be better to do it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Sheet0" || e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart != 4) return;
  //e.source.toast("Gate")
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange('c5:J5');
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  rg.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  rg.offset(0,-1).setValues(vs);
}
```

This will remove the old day and clear the last column that's not being used after the move.